# Why do I get NumberFormatException while converting String Array to int Array?

Tags: java, regex, string, numberformatexception, parseint

I do not get the Error when I run my code on **IntelliJ**. However, when I try to hand in my Code for the assignement Im working on, I get NFE for both test cases. I deleted all of my Code and let only the bellow code run through the test cases. Somewhere in here must be a `NumberFormatException`.

```
public class Search {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        int[] list = new int[n];
        String [] tokens = sc.nextLine().trim().split(" ");

        for (int i=0; i<tokens.length;i++){
            list[i]=Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I read about double spaces and checked this with: `System.out.println(Arrays.asList(tokens).contains(""));`
Output was false so this is not an option. As you can see I'm already using `trim()`.
I'd appreciate your help.
Louis

Eddit:
Alright something is fishy here. I added

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(tokens).contains(""));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
```

To my Code and handed it in to the test cases. While IntelliJ would deliver false followed by an array of integers, the test case outputs:
true
[]
.
Therefore you all are right and I just falsely assumed that the input in my test cases would be similar to the example Input I was given in the assignment.

Edit2:

ALRIGHT!
I figured it out. The Input of the test cases was simply not the same format as the one in my test Input which looked a bit like this:

10
8 8 9 12 110 111 117 186 298 321
2
8 13

I assume that the sc.nextLine() that I included skipped integers that I needed to make my list. 
So the actual problem was not that extra spaces or anything, it was simply that I advanced past the input I wanted through my usage of sc.nextLine().
The answer that gave me the hint I needed, even tho I dont think this was intended came from Andronicus. 
Thanks to everybody else anyways.

Comment: try logging `tokens[i]` before parsing it. you will know, what is causing NFE.

Comment: Yep, you've got a non-Integer in tokens, which is causing the NFE. There's probably some sort of test case that is being run against your code that passes in non-numbers.

Comment: Use this `split("\\s+")` instead of `split(" ")`.

Comment: This was the explanation I came up with too. But please, take a look at the Input Im given:
10  
8 8 9 12 110 111 117 186 298 321  
These are the first two lines of my Input. To me this looks free of any non-Integer tokens. I also tried printing out my tokens-array. The result looks like this:
[8, 8, 9, 12, 110, 111, 117, 186, 298, 321]
Also free of non Integer members

Comment: The above input works fine with the code you posted. This means that this is not the whole code (so the problem is somewhere else) or this is not the input you pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know, that there is going to be an integer as an input and you're not worried about parsing, why not using this instead?

```
int input = sc.nextInt();
```

In your solution you would have to do:

```
Arrays.stream(sc.nextLine().trim().split(" ")).filter(s -> !s.matches("\\s")).toArray(String[]::new);
\\ or simplier
sc.nextLine().trim().split("\\s+")
```

Comment: This is a good point. I might even do that but I still would like to understand why my version wont work.

Comment: It's because of those white spaces you need to get rid of

Comment: @Louis I've added some explanation

Comment: As mentioned in my edit, the problem was a different InputFormat than expected. There were probably less newlines in the Input than I ecpected. Thus I skipped parts of the Input through the usage of sc.nextLine().
I solved the problem by using only sc.nextInt(). Your answer was correct.

Answer (score 2):

There's a number of possible causes:

1. There's a non-number in `tokens` -- eg. `9 1! 3 x 3` ...
2. The tokens are split by more than one space -- eg `9    3`

You should be able to tell by the text of the Number Format Exception. For example, in the case of multiple spaces, you'd get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

And for non-numbers (eg "a"), you'd get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a"

There are, of course, numerous possible solutions depending on what you want to do when you run into invalid input (do you ignore it? throw a special exception? try to strip out non-numbers?)

When you know your inputs are separated by whitespace, but don't know how much white-space, you  can use a regular expression to target multiple whitespaces in your `split` command:

```
str.split("\\s+"); // splits on one or more whitespace including tabs, newlines, etc.
```

Then, to handle non-digits in your token list, you can add a check in your for-loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
  if(tokens[i].matches("\\d+")) {
    list[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
  } else {
    // Handle error case for non-digit input
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is likely due to the extra bunch of spaces between the numbers.

For Example,

```
9    8 7 9    1
  ^^       ^^
*Note: You have more than one spaces here.
```

This is how your array will look after splitting,

```
tokens = {"9", "", "", "", "8", "7", "9", "", "", "", "1"}
```

Above will throw the `NumberFormatException` because of extra spaces.

You can try `trimming` the contents again,

```
int i = 0;
for (String token : tokens){
    token = token.trim();
    if (!"".equals(token)) {
        list[i++] = Integer.parseInt(token);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. The array will look like this: `{"9","","","8","7",...}`. I know this because I tried it. ;)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Yes, you are right. I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: since I printed out the array and it looked like this:

[8, 8, 9, 12, 110, 111, 117, 186, 298, 321]
I was sure that extra spaces wouldnt be the reason for my problem.

Comment: It's still off. There will never be *any* spaces in the tokens array because that's your split character. There will be an empty string in place of each doubled space.

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your code to this  :

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the size of the array : ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        int[] list = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Enter a string : ");
        /** This regex will work for string having more than one space. */ 
        String trimmedToken = sc.nextLine().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
        String[] tokens = trimmedToken.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            list[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
            System.out.println(list[i]);
        }
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

Console Input :

```
Enter the size of the array : 
5
Enter a string : 
1       2     3      4    5
```

Output :

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Still fails for input: `1 2   3  x y  z`

Comment: This fails because String to int explicit type-casting is done in his code. So, you can't send string values in that which are not castable to integer.